# Вхождение элемента в множественный список

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Столкнулся с проблемой, поиска элементов списка в другом множественном списке.
Имеется список с mac адресами:

```
mac = [mac1, mac2, mac3]
```

Множественный список с MAC и IP:

```
device = [[mac1,ip1],[mac2,ip2],[mac3,ip3]]
```

Я пытаюсь найти какой элемент из списка `mac` отсутствует в списке `device`.
Пробовал реализовывать:

```
i = 0    
for values in mac:
        while i <= len(device)-1:
            if values not in device[i][0]:
                print('No')
            i += 1
```

Но это кроме того, что выглядит очень не красиво, еще и проверяет только первый элемент списка `mac`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно такое реализовать?
Пытался через map но так и не понял как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто делать поиск элементов из второго списка в первом:

```
mac = ['mac1', 'mac2', 'mac3']
device = [['mac1','ip1'],['mac2','ip2'],['mac3','ip3']]

for dev in device:
    if dev[0] in mac:
        print (dev[0]+" found")
```

будет:

```
mac1 found
mac3 found
```

**UPDATE** (добавлены пояснения автора вопроса):

```
mac = ['mac1', 'mac2', 'mac3']
device = [['mac1','ip1'],['mac5','ip2'],['mac3','ip3']]

#1 - есть в mac, но нет в device:
[x for x in mac if x not in (y[0] for y in device)]
#['mac2']

#2 - есть в device, но нет в mac:
[x[0] for x in device if x[0] not in mac]
#['mac5']
```

Comment: Забыл уточнить, список mac это все маки которые появлялись в сети за все время, device это список которые сейчас онлайн, и я хочу проверить если он есть в списке mac но его нет в device значит он offline. Как вы предложили, получается я нахожу все маки которые в данный момент онлайн,  Если он есть в device значит это не новое устройство и оно онлайн, если его нет в device это новое устройство.  Но как мне проверить тех кто есть в device но нет в mac?

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать в виде функции.

```
def finder(value, _list):
    if value in _list : return True
    for val in _list:
        if (type(val) == list or type(val) == tuple) and finder(value, val) == True : return True
    return False

list1 = ['mac1', 'mac2', 'mac3']
list2 = [['mac1', 'ip1'], ['mac4', 'ip2'], ['mac3', 'ip3']]

for val in list1:
    print(finder(val, list2))

# True
# False
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mac = ['mac1', 'mac2', 'mac3', 'mac4']
device = [['mac1','ip1'],['mac3','ip3']]
print(set(mac) - set(el[0] for el in device)) # {'mac4', 'mac2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение конкретно вашего случая, выводит Yes если елемент найден в списке device и No если не найден:

```
mac = ['mac1', 'mac2', 'mac3', 'mac4']
device = [['mac1','ip1'],['mac2','ip2'],['mac3','ip3']]
for item in mac:
    print("Yes" if any(item == e[0] for e in device) else "No")
```

НО я бы рекомендовал реализовать второй список - словарем, примерно вот так:

```
mac = ['mac1', 'mac2', 'mac3', 'mac4']
device = {'mac1': 'ip1', 'mac2': 'ip2', 'mac3':'ip3'}
print([item for item in mac if item not in device])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mac = ['mac1', 'mac2', 'mac3', 'mac4', 'mac5']
device = [['mac1','ip1'],['mac2','ip2'],['mac3','ip3']]

[(i,i in [j[0] for j in device]) for i in mac]

[('mac1', True), ('mac2', True), ('mac3', True), ('mac4', False), ('mac5', False)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Гм. Использовать тип, более приспособленный для поиска?

```
device_index = dict(device)
for value in mac:
    if value not in device_index:
        print value
```